# How to have subscripts in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, subscripts

I am trying to have this paper in my bibliography http://apl.aip.org/resource/1/applab/v1/i4/p82_s1

I export the BibTeX file and put it in my `.bib`. But it is shown like this:

> `FROM Ga(As[sub 1 - x]P[sub x])`

instead of proper chemical formula with subscripts. I use the `ieeetran` style. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Use `title=Coherent (visible) light emission from {Ga(As$_{1−x}$P$_{x}$)} junctions}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! Have a look at [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format.

Comment: @egreg suggestion works thanks. However I will have many references with formulas, which means modifying the exported .bib data manually for every entry.

Comment: @allse I don't think we can teach XML to BibTeX, it's too old for that. `;-)`

Comment: @allse it might be possible to use a decent text editor with regex find&replace to do a lot of the hard work on this (e.g. notepad++ on windows). Of course, learning regexes from scratch may be overkill for this.  I work on AlGaN so as you can imagine the same problem occurs in a lot of my references.  I have `${\mathrm{Al}}_{x}{\mathrm{Ga}}_{1-x}\mathrm{N}$` working perfectly in the title field in my .bib